# YouTube API loadVideoById some times not working?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I am working on this code. Some times the videos play well but some times it's showing a white screen and I am getting this type of error message:
player.loadVideoById is not a function.

My HTML code:

```
    <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" id="play_btn" onclick="playyoutubevideo('<?php echo $topic_names1['youtube_video_id']?>');"></i>
```

This is my javascript code:

```
var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          videoId: $('#video_id').val(),
             playerVars: { 'fs':'0' },
     events: {
             'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

   // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {            
         $('#popup_close').click(); 
        }
    }

function playyoutubevideo(video_id)
{

  $("body").css("position", "fixed"); 
   if(player)
    {
        var fn = function(){ player.loadVideoById(video_id); }
        setTimeout(fn, 500);

    }

   $(".pos_popup").removeClass("none1");
  $(".pos_popup1").removeClass("none1");  


}
```

If anyone knows the mistake, please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: can you create a fiddle